# Is the orthogonal basis obtained for $A$ a basis for $B^{\bot}$ where $B$ is a subspace of $A$?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be an inner product space of dimension $n$ with inner product $\langle\,,\,\rangle$.

Let $B$ be subspace of $A$, and let $\{a_1, ..., a_m\}$ be a basis for $B$.

Suppose that $\{a_1, ..., a_m, a_{m+1}, ..., a_n\}$ is a basis for $A$. Let $\{{a_1}', {a_2}', ..., {a_m}', ..., {a_n}'\}$ be the orthogonal basis for $A$ obtained by an application of the Gauss-Schmidt orthogonalization process on $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m, ..., a_n\}$.

Show that $\{a_{m+1}', ..., {a_n}'\}$ is a basis for $B^{\bot}$, and, $A = B + B^{\bot} $

Attempt:

Choose any orthonormal basis $E = \{e_1, ..., e_k\} \in B$.

Continue $E$ to a basis $E^{\bot} = \{e_1, ..., e_k; f_{k+1}, ..., f_n\}$ in $A$.

Applying GSOP to $E^{\bot}$. The first $k$ vectors in $E^{\bot}$ are orthogonal. So, GSOP alters nothing.

The remaining $n-k$ vectors may change, and we get the orthonormal basis $E^{\bot\bot} = \{e_1, ..., e_k; e_{k+1}, ..., e_n\}$ in $A$.

The vectors $e_{k+1}, ..., e_n$ are orthogonal to $e_1, ..., e_k$, and so they are all in $B^{\bot}$.

Present any $a\in A$ as the linear combination $a = (x_1e_1 + ... + x_ke_k) + (x_{k+1}e_{k+1} + ... + x_ne_n) = b + b'$

Hence, $b\in B$ and $b' \in B^{\bot}$. Which means that $\{a_{m+1}', ..., {a_n}'\}$ is a basis for $B^{\bot}$

Comment: $\{a_1,\dots,a_m,a_{m+1},\dots,a_n\}$ is a basis for $A$, not $B$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Yes! I Do have an attempt. I'll update my post once I think it's worth checking.

Comment: It is work remembering that, from Graham-Schmidt, the subspace generated by $a_1’,\dots,a_k’$ is the same as the subspace generated by $a_1,\dots ,a_k$ for each $k.$

Comment: Hi! Here's my attempt. Is my proof convincing? It's not really a proper proof, so I wish to see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{a_{m + 1}', \ldots, a_n'\}$ is orthonormal, it is also linearly independent (alternatively, since it is a subset of a linearly independent set). All you have to do is show that its span is $B^\perp$. To do this, let $b \in B^\perp$ and write it as a (unique) linear combination of the vectors in the orthonormal basis on $A$ (you should end up with a linear combination whose only nonzero coefficients are those for $a_{m + 1}', \ldots, a_n'$).

It seems that the key fact you're missing is that since $\{a_1', \ldots, a_n'\}$ is orthonormal,
$$b = \langle b, a_1'\rangle a_1' + \cdots + \langle b, a_n'\rangle a_n'.$$
To finish the proof, you just use the definition of $B^\perp$ and the fact that $a_1', \ldots, a_m' \in B$.

Comment: Can you walk me through step by step? The way I understand it is, continuing my work, we let $b \in B^{\bot}$, then we decompose it (with respect to the basis we get on $A$), then we end up with $\{{a_{m+1}}', ..., {a_n}'\}$? I'm not sure I know what happens under "decomposition".

Comment: Do you know why are orthonormal bases nice?

Comment: Because the coordinate representations have the same lengths as the original vectors, and make the same angles with each other?

Comment: That's not quite what you need. I've edited my answer to give more steps.

Comment: I see. Was my attempt wrong?

Comment: In your attempt, you don't really shown that $\operatorname{span}\{a_{m + 1}', \ldots, a_n'\} = B^\perp$, only that its a subset (also, you use $\in$ where you mean $\subset$ when defining $E$). I would also like to point out that your presentation is hard to follow. I wouldn't bother introducing all those extra bases; just stick with those in your third paragraph.

Comment: In your answer, you mentioned at the last part that I have to use the definition of $B^{\bot}$ but I did not define $B$ in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125025/discussion-between-themathandlanguagetutor-and-muw).